# How to pass response from one function to another function using ajax in django HTML?

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to pass flight data which is in dictionary form and this is generated when user searches for flight and selects offer.

What I want is the flight data should be passed in the url but user should not be able to read or modify it.
Currently, I have passed flight data with

```
  {% for  flight in response %}
      href="{% url 'get_detail' flight %}"
  {% endfor %}
```

but it shows flight information in URL like 127.0.0.1/get_detail/{flightinfohere}
. Is there any idea so that I can save this flight data for another function without passing in URL or I can hide this data or encode it?
Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to use AJAX, but I don't know how to pass the flight data in ajax as it is response of another views.py function.

Answer (score 0):

you can use post request or set cookie.

but the cookie method is easier

in template use :

```
{% for  flight in response %}
    <a href="{% url 'get_detail'%}" class="use-post" data-flight="{flight}">
{% endfor %}

....
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'%}"></script>
<script>
    $( ".user-post" ).click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const value = $(this).attr('href');
        const data = $(this).data('flight')
        $.cookie("flight_info",data)
        document.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

in view :

```
...

    flight_info = request.COOKIES.get('flight_info')
```